# How to translate query from Mongo to C#?

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb

```
db.getCollection('JobInfoRecords').find({info:{$regex: /<.*?password>/i}}).forEach
(
    function(document) 
    {
       var info = document.info;
       document.info = info.replace(/<(.*?password)>([^<]+)<\/(.*?password)>/gmi, "<$1></$3>");
       db.products.save(document);
    }
);
```

I'm trying to translate this code to C#.

```
var records = db.GetCollection<JobInfoRecord>("JobInfoRecords");
```

Can you help me to continue my translation to C#?

I return all documents from the collection `JobInfoRecords` where `info` have tags which name contain `password`. Then I destroy values of all of this tags using `regex`.

Comment: use a filter builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var records = db.GetCollection<JobInfoRecord>("JobInfoRecords");
var products = db.GetCollection<Product>("Products");
var rgx = new Regex(@"/<.*?password>/i"); 
records.Find(x => rgx.IsMatch(x.Info)).ForEachAsync( r =>
 {       
    r.Info = Regex.Replace(r.Info, @"/<(.*?password)>([^<]+)<\/(.*?password)", "<$1></$3>");
    products.InsertOneAsync(r);
 });
```